# PyCharm exibe classe do objeto ao invés do objeto em si

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

Olá,

Estou treinando o uso de alguns pacotes em Python 3.x, e uso PyCharm Community 2020.3.3. Quando tento personalizar gráficos e tabelas usando pacotes como pandas e seaborn o PyCharm não exibe o que quero, e sim a classe dele. Já tentei com o `print` tradicional e com o `display` importado do IPython. Segue um pequeno exemplo:

```
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display, HTML
import seaborn as sns

paulistinha = {"Rodada 1": [3, 3, 1, 0], "Rodada 2": [3, 1, 0, 3], "Rodada 3": [3, 3, 3, 3], "Rodada 4": [3, 0, 3, 1]}
linhas = ["Palmeiras", "Corinthians", "São Paulo", "Santos"]
classifica = pd.DataFrame(paulistinha, index=linhas)

display(HTML(classifica.to_html()))
dfa = classifica.head(2)
display(HTML(dfa.to_html()))

cm = sns.light_palette('green', as_cmap=True)
s = classifica.style.background_gradient(cmap=cm)
print(s)
display(s)

print(classifica.boxplot())
```

Quando tento fazer rodar esses 5 exemplos, ao invés de receber tabelas coloridas ou um belo gráfico de boxplot, recebo a seguinte saída:

```
<IPython.core.display.HTML object>
<IPython.core.display.HTML object>
<pandas.io.formats.style.Styler object at 0x017104F0>
<pandas.io.formats.style.Styler object at 0x017104F0>
AxesSubplot(0.125,0.11;0.775x0.77)
```

No caso dos comandos `.to_html` e `.boxplot()`, a inspeção do PyCharm me diz `Expected type 'tuple', got 'xxxx' instead`, sendo xxxx = HTML no caso de `.to_html` e xxxx = Styler para o `.boxplot()`.

Quando jogo os mesmos códigos no Google COLab roda liso.

Eu procurei aqui no Stack Overflow em PT e não achei absolutamente nada similar. Em inglês, até acho algumas coisas parecidas, mas como não domino muito bem o idioma não sei quão próxima são as soluções do que necessito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É exibido diretamente no Google Colab porque **a expressão é avaliada da forma que foi enviada, o propósito é diferente para o ambiente**. Para fazer com que os *plots* sejam exibidos no seu código local é necessário chamar o método `show()` do `matplotlib.pyplot`, algo como:

Começo do arquivo, importando o módulo:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

E para exibir o `plot`, definimos o mesmo com o método `boxplot` e chamamos o método `show`:

```
classifica.boxplot()
plt.show()
```

O resultado seria:

[image: Gráfico exibindo resultado da expressão]

Para os casos em que chama os métodos para exibir o conteúdo em `HTML`, você está chamando o método `display` (que exibe a expressão avaliada passada como argumento nos *outputs* disponíveis) e chamando métodos e funções que transformem as expressões em HTML, como em uma das linhas:

```
display(HTML(classifica.to_html()))
```

Perceba que, na linha acima, **duas funções são chamadas para transformar o objeto atual em uma `string` em HTML, mas a função `HTML()` não está retornando uma `string` e sim um novo tipo de objeto**, por isso recebe ele descrito no output (terminal, neste caso):

```
<IPython.core.display.HTML object>
```

Para mais informações sobre objetos do tipo e funções disponíveis no IPython, recomendo consultar [sua documentação](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) mais a fundo.

Já apenas a expressão `to_html()` do seu objeto `classifica` retorna uma `string`. Terá o retorno do HTML corretamente ao usar a função `display` para exibi-lo. Como no exemplo:

```
display(classifica.to_html())
```

O resultado seria:

```html
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>Rodada 1</th>
      <th>Rodada 2</th>
      <th>Rodada 3</th>
      <th>Rodada 4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Palmeiras</th>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Corinthians</th>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>São Paulo</th>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Santos</th>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Para o HTML estilizado, pode obter uma `string` em HTML a partir do método `render` no retorno da estilização do seu *plot*:

```
s = classifica.style.background_gradient(cmap=cm)
rendered_plot = s.render()
display(rendered_plot)
```

Tendo como resultado:

```html
<style  type="text/css" >
#T_2b2a5_row0_col0,#T_2b2a5_row0_col1,#T_2b2a5_row0_col3,#T_2b2a5_row1_col0,#T_2b2a5_row2_col3,#T_2b2a5_row3_col1{
            background-color:  #008000;
            color:  #f1f1f1;
        }#T_2b2a5_row0_col2,#T_2b2a5_row1_col2,#T_2b2a5_row1_col3,#T_2b2a5_row2_col1,#T_2b2a5_row2_col2,#T_2b2a5_row3_col0,#T_2b2a5_row3_col2{
            background-color:  #ebf3eb;
            color:  #000000;
        }#T_2b2a5_row1_col1,#T_2b2a5_row2_col0,#T_2b2a5_row3_col3{
            background-color:  #9ccd9c;
            color:  #000000;
        }</style><table id="T_2b2a5_" ><thead>    <tr>        <th class="blank level0" ></th>        <th class="col_heading level0 col0" >Rodada 1</th>        <th class="col_heading level0 col1" >Rodada 2</th>        <th class="col_heading level0 col2" >Rodada 3</th>        <th class="col_heading level0 col3" >Rodada 4</th>    </tr></thead><tbody>
                <tr>
                        <th id="T_2b2a5_level0_row0" class="row_heading level0 row0" >Palmeiras</th>
                        <td id="T_2b2a5_row0_col0" class="data row0 col0" >3</td>
                        <td id="T_2b2a5_row0_col1" class="data row0 col1" >3</td>
                        <td id="T_2b2a5_row0_col2" class="data row0 col2" >3</td>
                        <td id="T_2b2a5_row0_col3" class="data row0 col3" >3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                        <th id="T_2b2a5_level0_row1" class="row_heading level0 row1" >Corinthians</th>
                        <td id="T_2b2a5_row1_col0" class="data row1 col0" >3</td>
                        <td id="T_2b2a5_row1_col1" class="data row1 col1" >1</td>
                        <td id="T_2b2a5_row1_col2" class="data row1 col2" >3</td>
                        <td id="T_2b2a5_row1_col3" class="data row1 col3" >0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                        <th id="T_2b2a5_level0_row2" class="row_heading level0 row2" >São Paulo</th>
                        <td id="T_2b2a5_row2_col0" class="data row2 col0" >1</td>
                        <td id="T_2b2a5_row2_col1" class="data row2 col1" >0</td>
                        <td id="T_2b2a5_row2_col2" class="data row2 col2" >3</td>
                        <td id="T_2b2a5_row2_col3" class="data row2 col3" >3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                        <th id="T_2b2a5_level0_row3" class="row_heading level0 row3" >Santos</th>
                        <td id="T_2b2a5_row3_col0" class="data row3 col0" >0</td>
                        <td id="T_2b2a5_row3_col1" class="data row3 col1" >3</td>
                        <td id="T_2b2a5_row3_col2" class="data row3 col2" >3</td>
                        <td id="T_2b2a5_row3_col3" class="data row3 col3" >1</td>
            </tr>
    </tbody></table>
```

Dado que as expressões são avaliadas de forma diferente no *Google Colab*, para que não tenha que copiar e colar o código em HTML em algum site ou arquivo e avaliar no browser, acredito que a biblioteca [imgkit](https://pypi.org/project/imgkit/) com [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/) seja uma boa escolha, salvando o conteúdo avaliado em um arquivo local, como no exemplo:

```
import imgkit
imgkit.from_string(classifica.to_html(), 'rendered_plot.png')
```

Mais informações de como fazer o `imgkit` rodar de forma correta estão em sua documentação, acredito que as referências incluídas possuam mais informações caso as necessite.

Comment: Funcionou perfeito para o boxplot, mas não para as tabelas do IPython (classifica.to_html) e nem para as tabelas do Pandas (classifica.style.background_gradient). Suponho que seja o mesmo tipo de problema (algum comando), mas não consigo encontrar. Na verdade, encontrei um lugar falando para converter para float, mas nao funcionou.

Comment: @GiovanniVM editei a resposta e complementei com algumas informações as quais acredito ser o que necessita.

Comment: Legal, isso resolve mais uma das questões. Falta só a última, da tabela de cores com seaborn e pandas ( cm = sns.light_palette('green', as_cmap=True) / s = classifica.style.background_gradient(cmap=cm) ). As soluções de transformar em float não funcionaram. Desculpa ter tantas perguntas em uma, quando criei a questão achei que os três teriam uma solução única.

Comment: @GiovanniVM o que mencionou das tabelas de cores está na parte em que explico como usar a estilização do seu plot: "Para o HTML estilizado, pode obter uma string em HTML a partir do método render no retorno da estilização do seu plot..."

O snippet seguinte exibe a tabela com cores como descreveu.

Comment: Cara, ralei como um cão, fiquei um tempão entendendo cada parte do que vc escreveu, fucei um monte no pacote imgkit e no wkhtmltopdf, e finalmente consegui compreender e resolver. Sensacional. Agradeço demais.

Comment: Se me permite um último comentário-pergunta, para não criar outra pergunta: a diferença entre o PyCharm e o Google Colab, nesse caso, é que o Colab "conversa" com outra linguagem (HTML, no caso) enquanto a versão gratuita do PyCharm não o faz?

Comment: Não. O Google Colab (que usa o [Jupyter Notebook](https://jupyter-notebook-beginner-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/what_is_jupyter.html#what-is-the-jupyter-notebook)) não é uma "IDE" ou editor de código, é um ambiente que avalia o código quando enviado, lembrando o [REPL do Python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html). Ao usar o REPL vai perceber que ambos funcionam de forma parecida, avaliando o código no momento do envio. Se rodar seu código Python por fora e/ou escrever ele sem o PyCharm perceberá o mesmo comportamento, pois o PyCharm é apenas um editor nesse quesito.